# Java Lang nullpointer exception in animation example?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Images extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    DisplayMode dm = new DisplayMode(800,600,32, DisplayMode.REFRESH_RATE_UNKNOWN);
    Images I = new Images();
    I.run(dm);
}

private Screen s;
private Image bg;
private Image pic;
private boolean nLoaded;
Animation a;

    public void run(DisplayMode dm)
    {

        nLoaded = false;
         s = new Screen();
        try{

                s.Setfullscreen(dm, this);
                LoadPics();
                MovieLoop();
                try{
                Thread.sleep(50000);    
                }catch(Exception ex){}
        }finally{
            s.restoreScreen();
        }

    }

    public void MovieLoop(){
        long startingtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long cumTime = startingtime;

        while(cumTime-startingtime < 5000)
        {
            long timepassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - cumTime;
            cumTime += timepassed;

            a.update(timepassed);

            Graphics g = s.getFullScreenWindow().getGraphics();
            draw(g);
            g.dispose();

            try{
            Thread.sleep(20);
            }catch(Exception ex){}

        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(bg, 0,0, null);
        g.drawImage(a.getImage(),0,0,null); }


    //Create Load Pictures
    public void LoadPics()
    {
        bg = new ImageIcon("C:\\Gamepics\\BackgroundImage.jpg").getImage();
        pic = new ImageIcon("C:\\Gamepics\\SmileyIcon3.png").getImage();
        nLoaded = true;
        repaint();


    }


    public void paint(Graphics g){
        if(g instanceof Graphics2D){
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        }

        if(nLoaded)
        {
            g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(pic, 300,300, null);
        }
    }  
}
```

Im not understanding what I did wrong ive overlooked everything the best I can.  Im just practicing a simple animation and I keep getting 3 null pointer exceptions. 
Ive researched the best I can and apparently NullPointerExceptions in java have to do with trying to get the size of null arrays? The compiler hasn't marked any of my lists as problems so im a little confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated. All of the errors are commented out. There are three of them and they are in the Images class

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Images.MovieLoop(Images.java:45)
at Images.run(Images.java:26)
at Images.main(Images.java:8)
```

Animation Class

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.*;
public class Animation {

private ArrayList scenes;
private int sceneindex;
private long movietime;
private long totaltime;
//CONSTRUCTOR
public Animation(){
    scenes = new ArrayList();
    totaltime =0;
    start();

}
//Add scene to array list and sets time for each scene
//For example. If you have 3 scenes you would add t to total time three times. So if you had 
//3 Scenes, one for 1s, one for 2s, one for 3s. Total time would be 6s. and you would call addscene 3 times
public synchronized void addScene(Image i, long t)
{ 
    totaltime+=t;
    scenes.add(new OneScene(i, totaltime));

}
//start animation from beggininign inignngingingnig 
public synchronized void start(){
movietime = 0;
sceneindex = 0;
}
//change scenes 


//movie time is the sum of all the time passed from last update
//If you have more than one scene. timepassed gets added to movietime.
//if movietime is greater than or equal to total time(ie. animation is complete) restart the animation
public synchronized void update(long timepassed)
{
    if(scenes.size() > 1){
        movietime += timepassed;
        if(movietime >= totaltime)
        {
            movietime = 0;
            sceneindex = 0;

        }
        while(movietime > getScene(sceneindex).endTime)
        {
            sceneindex++;
        }
    }
}

public synchronized Image getImage(){
    if(scenes.size() == 0){
        return null;}
    else{
        return getScene(sceneindex).pic;
    }
}
//Getscene
private OneScene getScene(int x){
    return (OneScene)scenes.get(x);
}
//Scenes are gonna be 
private class OneScene{
    Image pic;
    long endTime;

    public OneScene(Image pic, long endTime)
    {
        this.pic = pic;
                this.endTime = endTime;

    }
}
}
```

I included the animation class because the compiler is highlighting these three method calls as the source of the problem

```
    a.update(timepassed); 
    MovieLoop(); 
     I.run(dm);
```

Comment: Show us your error message

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for others to find the error, it would help if you would add the stacktrace of your error messages.

Answer (score 1):

*Please Note: This is a really long comment*

Let's start with `Graphics g = s.getFullScreenWindow().getGraphics();` - `getGraphics` is NEVER a good idea, this can return `null`.

You should NEVER try and update any UI component from any thread other the EDT and you should NEVER draw directly to it in this manner, instead, you should be using `paintComponent`.

You should NEVER `dispose` of any `Graphics` context that you did not create yourself, this will prevent other components from been painted.

You should avoid overriding `paint`, especially of a top level container, if for no other reason, it's not double buffered (the top level container), and you will also be painting over any other child components.

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

You should try using `ImageIO` instead of `ImageIcon`.  `ImageIO` will throw exceptions if it can't read the file, where as `ImageIcon` simply fails silently, no very helpful.

Comment: 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Images.MovieLoop(Images.java:45)
 at Images.run(Images.java:26)
 at Images.main(Images.java:8)
'

Comment: I'm guessing that's `Graphics g = s.getFullScreenWindow().getGraphics();`